# How to change execution time limit in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have defined a python function (as a .py file) that fits some scientific data, in a iterative way, for a few dozens of files. And now, I am trying to import this function, in a jupyter notebook, to use as part of another script, to process the obtained data. It is basically something like:

```
from python_file import defined_function

filename = 'name of the file'

results = defined_function(filename)
```

This script would naturally take a few minute to end in my machine. However, before it finishes I get an error message, related to the time limit:

```
RuntimeError: Execution exceeded time limit, max runtime is 30s
```

How do I change this time limit in my notebook? If it helps, I'm using the ipython version 6.1.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit = 10000000 in jupyter_notebook_config.py will does the trick. Please note that before you could even see a file named jupyter_notebook_config.py and then, proceed with this fixing, you must run first jupyter notebook --generate-config (For linux users).

If Overriding this in the config file doesn't work for you. Same error regardless of what you set NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit =  to in the config file. It shouldn't be in the correct place already. If not, try putting 'NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit =  ' at ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py.